# Combine two specific Linux commands into one

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to make a combination of 2 Linux commands:

1st command:

```
cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c "echo -e \"\n{}\"; chage -l {}" >> users-list.log
```

2nd command:

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f7
```

1st command takes the users and all details about each users and the 2nd command takes the login shell.

Currently, the first command has the following output:

```
dante
Last password change                    : Aug 18, 2017
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7

marion
Last password change                    : Aug 28, 2017
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
```

I would like that my new output in my users-list.log file to look like this(the spacing for "Linux sheel" doesn't matter):

```
dante
Last password change                    : Aug 18, 2017
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
Linux shell                                         : /bin/bash

marion
Last password change                    : Aug 28, 2017
Password expires                    : never
Password inactive                   : never
Account expires                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 0
Maximum number of days between password change      : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
Linux shell                                         : /bin/bash
```

Is any way to achieve this with a single command?

Best regards,
Romain

Comment: `[first command] >> userlist.log && cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f7 >> userlist.log`

Comment: Put the commands in a script-file, make the script-file executable, and put it somewhere in the `PATH`. Now you can use it as a single command. You can also make a function and put it in e.g. `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: You might be interested in the command `finger $USER | grep -oP 'Shell: \K.*'` This will return the default shell of the user. You can embed this in your first command.

Comment: @kvantour: Thanks for your solution. Your solution might work, but I should not install any other modules than default. Therefore, I would prefer users666N's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command

```
cat /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c 'a=`echo "{}" | cut -f1 -d:`; echo -e "\n$a"; chage -l $a; echo -e "Linux shell\t: " `echo "{}" | cut -f7 -d:`' >> users-list.log
```

which is broken down below for readability

```
cat /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c '
  a=`echo "{}" | cut -f1 -d:`;
  echo -e "\n$a";
  chage -l $a;
  echo -e "Linux shell\t: " `echo "{}" | cut -f7 -d:`
' >> users-list.log
```

The commands within backticks are evaluated by the shell.
Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48392/understanding-backtick

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted. I prefer your way because it's scalable for the other tabs as well

Comment: Is any way to escape the characters from the command? I would need to run in Ansible. I've tried something like this, but didn't worked: `'cat /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c "a=`echo \"{}\" | cut -f1 -d:`; echo -e \"\n$a\"; chage -l $a; echo -e \"Linux shell\t: \\" `echo \"{}\" | cut -f7 -d:`" >> users-list.log'`

Comment: I think it would be better to use a bash script file with Ansible.